# ASP.NET Select item from ListView not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, selectedindexchanged

I wanted to call the ListView's SelectedIndexChanged method but it doesn't go in to the SelectedIndexChanged method in runtime. Here's my code.

```
<asp:ListView ID="LeftsideMessageList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"  DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LeftsideMessageList_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void LeftsideMessageList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

           string pid = LeftsideMessageList.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
           MessageBusinessClass MBC = new MessageBusinessClass();
           string x = pid;
           int id = Convert.ToInt32(x);
           var grouplist = MBC.getSpecificGroup(x, Session["Username"].ToString()); //session
           Session["Groupname"] = grouplist.GroupName;
           Session["REmail"] = grouplist.Recipient.Email;   // message to

           GetRightMessageList(grouplist.Recipient.Email);

}
```

EDIT:

I had a LinkButton which I used to call the method from but I removed it and wanted to use the item selected event to call the method instead.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect"   runat="server"  ForeColor="White" >
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set [AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true

```
<asp:ListView ID="LeftsideMessageList" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"  DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LeftsideMessageList_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
```

Comment: Still doesn't get called. The ListView is dynamic and items get added during the load event. Also check the new EDIT :)

Answer (score -2):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
<asp:ListView ID="LeftsideMessageList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"  DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LeftsideMessageList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

Comment: Still doesn't get called. The ListView is dynamic and items get added during the load event. Also check the new EDIT :)

Comment: Make sure you have put this inside form tag. like this form runat="server" if it is content page than master page should have this  form runat="server"